# Android mapview not loading tiles in some locations

Tags: android, google-maps

so i am using the Google Maps API V2 in my app. the problem is when i test the app from my location in Lagos, Nigeria the map works fine, but when it is tested in say Las Vegas, USA the mapview tiles don't load, it just shows a blank fragment with the Google logo but the MAP Directions API returns data. Does anyone know why this is happening and how this can be fixed?
Below is a screenshot of the app with the two different locations. Thanks in advance guys.

[image]

Comment: If there is an error with tiles loading you should see corresponding message in Logcat. Can you post the Logcat as well?

Comment: there's no error in Logcat as it is fetching the directions as is supposed to but it's just not loading the tile and not showing any error in Logcat.